# How to get Child Generic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I define class BaseController with Generic Class TEntity.

```
public class BaseController<TEntity> : Controller
```

Use:

```
public class ProductController : BaseController<Product>
    {
        public ProductController(BaseService<Product> baseService)
            : base(baseService)
        {

        }

    }
```

Class Product has Child properties relationship. It's dynamic follow TEntity (class Product)

```
public partial class Product
    {

        [Key]
        public long CodeId { get; set; }



        public int Name { get; set; }

        //Config Ref
        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
    }

public partial class ProductDetail
        {

            [Key]
            public long CodeId { get; set; }



            public int Name { get; set; }


        }
```

TEntity now is Product. And I get property of ProductDetails.

```
var tEn = JsonUtilities.ConvertObjectToObject<TEntity>(obj);    

    var propsInfo = (typeof(TEntity)).GetProperties();

    var propsCollection = propsInfo.Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType
        && x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));


    foreach (var prop in propsCollection)
    {
        dynamic childItems = prop.GetValue(tEn);

        var genericType = prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var tableProp = context.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == genericType.Name);

        foreach (dynamic itemChild in childItems)
        {
            // Convert here for setting some property value
            var dy = JsonUtilities.ConvertObjectToObject<dynamic>(itemChild);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> itemKey in dic)
            {
                itemChild[itemKey.Value.Trim()] = "DATA" ;  << dynamic property
            }

            // QUESTION HERE
            var itemChild2 =  JsonUtilities.ConvertObjectToObject<ABC???>(dy);  <<<<< 

        } 
    }
```

Now, how can I can convert again generic itemChild with Class Object ProductDetail

```
var dy = JsonUtilities.ConvertObjectToObject<ProductDetail>(itemChild);  <<< I can not put ProductDetail here because, It's child of generic object Product.
```

I have TEntity is Product, and in Product have ProductDetails is CHILD. (I've used name Product & ProductDetail for you easy understand.)

Now, I've TEntity is Product. I can get Child Instant of Class ProductDetail. maybe,call 'childClass'. 
After that, I convert 'childClass' to dynamic object, My Question is How to convert again to 'childClass' from dynamic Object.

Comment: This code is very confusing. As far as I get, you want to add some extra dynamic details to a product. Also you use `EF Core`. If this is true, then you probably should use foreign keys and let database manage that for you.

Comment: oh, no. not relationship with ef core. It's just example about. 
I have TEntity is Product, and in Product have ProductDetails. (I've used name Product & ProductDetail for you easy understand.)
Now, I've TEntity  is Product. I can get Child Instant of Class ProductDetail. maybe,call childClass. 
after that, I convert ProductDetail to dynamic, and want convert again to ProductDetail.

Comment: Still it's confusing. Maybe it's good practice to use Foo and Bar for this kind of examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `Interface`. Every type that might be used in such scenario (ex. ProductDetail) should implement that interface. In this case, there is no need to multiple conversions.
I've recapped this.

```
namespace Project
{
    class Product
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails {get;set;}
    }

    class ProductDetail : IInjectable
    {
        public int Key {get;set;}
        public string Value {get;set;}
    }

    interface IInjectable
    {
        int Key {get;set;}
        string Value {get;set;}
    }

    class Worker
    {
        void Do<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Dictionary<int, string> dic)
        {
            typeof(TEntity)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                            typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
                .Select(p =>
                {
                    var genType = p.PropertyType
                                   .GetGenericArguments()
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
                    return new
                    {
                        Property = p,
                        GenericType = genType,
                    };
                })
                .Where(item => typeof(IInjectable).IsAssignableFrom(item.GenericType))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item =>
                {
                    var enumerableValue = item.Property
                                              .GetValue(entity) as IEnumerable;
                    foreach (var v in enumerableValue)
                    {
                        if (v is IInjectable injectable)
                        {
                            injectable.Value = dic[injectable.Key];
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try with it. Thank you @Mohammad Azhdari

Answer (score 0):

You can make the call of the generic method using reflection.

```
                MethodInfo method = typeof(JsonUtilities).GetMethod(nameof(ConvertObjectToObject));
                MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(prop.PropertyType));
                var itemChild2 = generic.Invoke(this, dy);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I will try to do. Thank you OxQ

Comment: 'dy', we don't have it, if I does not know how to input ProductDetail